# How do I update YUM repositories?

Tags: yum

I am very, very new to all this so baby steps please if helping is appreciated.

I am trying to connect to the following repository so I can update my YUM packages:
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/SRPMS/

honestly I have no idea how to do that from SSH though - any guidance is very appreciative.

Comment: The better question is, why doesn't anyone update YUM repositories lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The instructions are listed at: http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/

```
rpm -ivh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/`uname -i`/webtatic-release-5-0.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: That seems a tiny bit easier than doing it by hand as I suggested ;)

Comment: this install does not contain SEVERAL updated packages (i.e. http, php, openssl, etc) for some reason, perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Once you install the repository, you may then `yum install <some package in the webtatic repository> --enablerepo=webtatic`, just like you would to install any other package.

Comment: guess it would help if I spelled the domain right ( webtatic, not webtactic) although I like the second better :)

Answer (score 10):

**yum clean metadata**

Taken from "man yum" ?clean

> ```
> CLEAN OPTIONS
>
>   yum clean expire-cache
>          Eliminate  the local data saying when the metadata and mirrorlists were downloaded for each repo. This means yum will revalidate the cache for each repo. next time it is used. However if the cache is still valid, nothing significant was deleted.
>
>   yum clean packages
>          Eliminate any cached packages from the system.  Note that packages are not automatically deleted after they are downloaded.
>
>   yum clean headers
>          Eliminate all of the header files, which old versions of yum used for dependency resolution.
>
>   yum clean metadata
>          Eliminate all of the files which yum uses to determine the remote availability of packages. Using this option will force yum to download all the metadata the next time it is run.
>
>   yum clean dbcache
>          Eliminate the sqlite cache used for faster access to metadata.  Using this option will force yum to download the sqlite metadata the next time it is run, or recreate the sqlite  metadata  if using an older repo.
>
>   yum clean rpmdb
>          Eliminate any cached data from the local rpmdb.
>
>   yum clean plugins
>          Tell any enabled plugins to eliminate their cached data.
>
>   yum clean all
>          Does  all  of  the  above.  As a convenience, if this command does not result in a completely empty cache due to the restrictions outlined at the beginning of this section, a message will be printed, saying how much disk space can be reclaimed by cleaning the remaining repos manually.  For this purpose, a repo is considered clean when its disk usage doesn't exceed 64KB (that  is to account for directory entries and tiny metadata files such as "productid" that are never cleaned).
> ```

Answer (score 5):

First you have to setup the repository in a configuration file for yum. Create the repo configuration like this:

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
# nano Webtatic
```

Insert something like this in the file

```
[webtatic] 
name=Webtatic repo
baseurl=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/SRPMS/
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy
```

Save and close the file. Then you import the key for the repo:

```
# rpm --import http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy
```

At this point the repository is added to yum. Now you only need to use it.

```
# yum update
```

Answer (score 1):

Yum downloads the package lists automatically, and the repositories are configured in files under /etc/yum.repos.d. Furthermore, it does not download source RPMs, see: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq#Q.14:HowcanItellyumtodownloadasourcepackagei.e.a.src.rpmfile

A minimal repo file for that site would look something like this:

```
[webtatic]
name=CentOS-5 - Webtatic.com
baseurl=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/$basearch/
```